# Redirect sub domain to another sub domain and keep page name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking to redirect a whole subdirectory to another but keep the page name when redirecting

example:

Example.
subdomain.example.com/test.php
to
subdomain2.example.com/test.php

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(data(?:/.*|))$ https://subdomain2.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But it doesn't redirect anywhere

Comment: What do you actually mean by "but keep the page name"? And are you really looking for a redirection or for a rewrite?

Comment: I mean keep the name example.php at the end of the domain...

Comment: So you want to keep the URL shown in the browser's address bar unaltered? OK. I would suggest you revise your question to make that clear. There is an "edit" button below your question. _Use it ..._